# Can I turn off hot reload when using nuxt?

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js

I started my vue/nuxt app with:

```
npx create-nuxt-app
```

And I'll like to turn off the hot reload feature when running the dev server. I can't find an option to do that anywhere. In the help for the nuxt command, there is:

```
nuxt --help
    Description
      Starts the application in development mode (hot-code reloading, error
      reporting, etc)
    Usage
      $ nuxt dev <dir> -p <port number> -H <hostname>
    Options
      --port, -p          A port number on which to start the application
      --hostname, -H      Hostname on which to start the application
      --spa               Launch in SPA mode
      --universal         Launch in Universal mode (default)
      --config-file, -c   Path to Nuxt.js config file (default: nuxt.config.js)
      --help, -h          Displays this message
```

with no switch to turn off hot reloading. I assume it might be possible in the `nuxt.config.js` file, but I haven't been able to find the possible option.

I've looked through the documentation starting at this page: https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build but I didn't see it.

Comment: any updates for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Blocking the request as described by @Pascal below was what I did. Seems like it is wasting a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Not the perfect solution below, but at least it stops hot-reloading.

For Nuxt 1.4.0 using Webpack 3 and Chrome (67.0.3396.99) DevTools:

1. Open Developer Tools in Chrome
2. Click on the three dots (...) on the right-top side
3. Click on More tools -> Request Blocking
4. Click "Enable Request blocking" and add "*hot-update.json"

[image]

This will stop the hot reload - but also throw an error msg.

Might help someone - it did it for me :)

Comment: Thanks, I've done this for now, but it doesn't seem like the right solution, so I'll leave the answer open for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I think its little late to answer this but adding this to nuxt.config.js will work

```
  build: {
      extend(config) {
          const hmrIndex = config.plugins.findIndex(p => p.constructor.name === 'HotModuleReplacementPlugin')
          config.plugins.splice(hmrIndex, 1)
      }
  }
```

so how this will behave is that it will recompile on change but won't refresh the page. If you manually do the refresh on browser new change will get reflected.

I am not if this is what the OP was looking for...

Answer (score -2):

In your nuxt.config.js

```
[![module.exports = {
...
  output: {
    publicPath: ''
  },
...
}
```

Here is the [solution](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/1251#issuecomment-392351817) and see the discussions in thread to understand more

[imageref](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikQKR.png)